# Android Email To Field Displaying

Tags: android, email

I am finally able to navigate to the email page. I know this is an issue people have had in the past but I was wondering if anyone had found a suitable answer. Thanks.

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {

```
                Intent displayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String[] extra = new String[ ]{"test@email.com"}; 
                displayIntent. putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, extra); 
                displayIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                displayIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //          
                _this.startActivity(displayIntent); 
            }
            return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying this on your emulator. What might happen in that case is that it will launch a message composing screen instead of the email screen that you were anticipating. Run this on an actual device and I think it will work.